# using xml attribute value in two different elements in result xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a Source XML which looks like this

```
<parent>
      <child id="123456">Child Name
      </child>
      <image name="child.jpg">
</parent>
```

The destination XML should be

```
<data>
     <person id="123456">
        <name>Child Name</name>
     </person>
     <relation id="123456">
        <filename>child.jpg</filename>
     </relation>
</data>
```

I am using XSLT to transform this. **The Problem** is that when how can i get the value of id (which is 123456) from  in source XML at two different places in Destination XML using XSLT.

Comment: @dradu: It isn't necessary to use variables in solving this problem -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a short and simple solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="parent">
     <data>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="child">
  <person id="{@id}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
  </person>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="image">
  <relation id="{preceding-sibling::child[1]/@id}">
   <filename><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></filename>
  </relation>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<parent>
    <child id="123456">Child Name</child>
    <image name="child.jpg"/>
</parent>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<data>
   <person id="123456">
      <name>Child Name</name>
   </person>
   <relation id="123456">
      <filename>child.jpg</filename>
   </relation>
</data>
```

Comment: @Touseef: What you cite as "simple" is unnecessarily complicated (no `xsl:element` and no `xsl:attribute' is necessary), inefficient and potentially buggy (`ancestor::MainStory/@kmsid` scans all ancestors and generally selects more than one node).

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, it was helping

Comment: @Touseef: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Could you, please, *accept* this answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer)?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:
**The XSL:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent">
            <!--variable to store @id-->
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="child/@id"/>
            <!--creating a test comment node()-->
            <xsl:comment>Child having id: <xsl:value-of select="child/@id"/></xsl:comment>
            <xsl:element name="person">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./child/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="relation">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="filename">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./image/@name"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input XML(yours but slightly modified to make it well*formed)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
      <child id="123456">Child Name</child>
      <image name="child.jpg"/>
</parent>
```

**And the result**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<data>
  <!--Child having id: 123456-->
  <person id="123456">
    <name>Child Name</name>
  </person>
  <relation id="123456">
    <filename>child.jpg</filename>
  </relation>
</data>
```

Comment: Careful - while this answer works for the OP's question, it might not be as comprehensive as the one proposed by @Dimitre Novatchev.  For instance, if their were two `<children>/<image>` element pairs inside of a `<parent>` element, yours would only return the first one.  Again, this isn't a scenario that the OP explicitly requested, but it's worth looking at.